# Using a master/index file with Flyway repeatable migrations

Tags: flyway

I'm wondering if Flyway allows the use a master file to re-enforce the execution orders of procedures, functions, views and triggers in repeatable migrations? Currently I have an in-house tool that generates master files for these objects so that they can be installed without errors (resolves the inter-dependency between them).

Has anyone had similar experience and how did you handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When Flyway finds multiple repeatable migrations that need to run (because they are new or have been modified), Flyway executes them in the alphabetical order of their descriptions.

This should easily allow you to achieve something similar to what your in-house tool did with its master file.